# There is an C function with pointers and a char return, what only returns the char value and 0 to the pointers

Tags: c, pointers, printf

The objective here is to print the student's average grade as a letter (A for Aprooved, R for Reprooved, or F for Miss, or Falta, in Portuguese), with the average grade value itself, and the student's total presence in classes, using pointers to avg and misses. But after compilation, only the char return value is printed, with 0 on the others.

I tried to print the stored values in the pointers *avg and *presence, but the program takes the student grade values and present values before crashing.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    char situation(float n1,float n2,float n3,int misses, int classes, float 
    *avg, float *presence);

    int main()
    {
        float *avg, *presence, vet[3];
        int f, a, x;
        printf("Write the value of your notes \n");

        for(x=0;x<=2;x++)
        {
            printf("Note %d:",x+1);
        
            scanf("%f",&vet[x]);
        }

        printf("Misses: ");
        scanf("%d",&f);
        printf("Given: ");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        char outcome=situation(vet[0], vet[1], vet[2], f, a, &avg, &presence);

        printf("With an average of %f and presence of %f percent, your situation is %c",avg,presence,outcome);
        return 0;
        }

    char situation(float n1,float n2,float n3,int misses, int classes, float 
    *avg, float *presence)
    {
        char result;
        *presence=((classes-misses)/classes)*100;
        *avg=(n1+n2+n3)/3;

        if(*presence>=0 && *presence<75)
        {
            result='F';
        }

        if(*presence>=75 && *presence <=100)
        {
            if(*avg>=0 && *avg<6);
            {
                result='R';
            }
            if(*avg>=6 && *avg<=10)
            {
                result='A';
            }
            if(*avg<0 || *avg>10)
            {
                result='x';
            }
        }
        if(*presence<0 || *presence>100)
        {
            result='x';
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I expected the student's total presence and the average grade as a value and letter (A, R, or F), printed on the terminal to the user, but it only returned the char result value.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly if you adopted an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and apply it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler issue the warnings for the `char outcome=situation(vet[0],vet[1],vet[2],f,a,&avg,&presence);` call?

Comment: Yes. I'm using dev c++ and he gives an passing6 for 'situation' from incomatible pointer type

Comment: i'm a new programmer, i really don't know how to fix it

Comment: if fix it removing the pointer on avg and presence on beginning of main, and only put them on function call.

Comment: thx for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has one main problem:

```
float *avg,*presence,
```

When you a calling

```
char outcome=situation(vet[0],vet[1],vet[2],f,a,&avg,&presence);
```

You are passing the address to the pointer you just declared. By changing the value in the function `outcome`, you are changing the address that `avg` and `presence` are pointing to, not the value of the variable.

Try changing to

```
float avg,presence
```

This way, when you change the value (using the `*` operator) you will change the actual variable value.

You may find this that `presence` still be showing as 0 on the printf. This is because how C works with types in arithmetics operations. Your division has only `ints` on it, so the result will be a `int`. Given the result will always be `>= 1`, the result will be rounded to the int value, which is 0.

To fix that just put a float value in the division and the result will be a `float.`
Something like:

```
*presence=((classes-misses)/(classes*1.0))*100;
```

Answer (score 0):

avg is a float pointer, you are sending it by pointer (&avg) so your function needs to be (int n1,....,float **avg,...)

Try to send avg without the &.
Give him a value before (it is better)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler warning pointed you directly to the problem. You should examine the warning and come to understand what it means and why it was issued.

Your error is here:

```
float *avg,*presence
```

These should be declared as `float`, not `float *`.